# url not showing in WebView inside a Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-webview

I'm trying to open this url in `WebView` in dialog: http://mtl2.liveatc.net/eham01_rdr_artip

But nothing happened (with other url everything works fine). I just see that app loading the page and when done - the dialog disappears.

Here is my code:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AtcInfo.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.web_dialog);
WebView wb = dialog.findViewById(R.id.webview);
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb.loadUrl(listUrl.get(position));
wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});

dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
```

And the `web_dialog.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

I was trying to resize `WebView`, but nothing works. I'll appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: Have you tried changing layout_height to match_parent on the webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a fixed height and width to your `ScrollView` and add `android:layout_weight="1"` as an extra attribute in your `WebView`. This should serve your purpose I think.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

It looks like this in my emulator.

[image: My emulator]

Comment: Thank you! You really saved my time!

Comment: Glad to know that helped.